# Pandas / python to autogenerate new values through a range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe read in from some CSV data. I have two numbers in seperate columns, representing a range and would like to do the following;

A) iterate through the data set
B) At each new index, calculate the range
C) create a total number of new rows based on the sum of that range (doesn't need to be in the existing dataframe)
D) And for each new row, insert incremental values through that range, concatanating specified column data, and retaining the original additional details from the other columns.

Example:

| value | range1 | range2 | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 3 | blue |
| b | 4 | 6 | yellow |

Result:

| output | value | colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | a | blue |
| a2 | a | blue |
| a3 | a | blue |
| b4 | b | yellow |
| b5 | b | yellow |
| b6 | b | yellow |

Comment: Your ranges are inconsistent. Why does the first row give `a1 a2 a3` and second row give `b4 b5 b6`?

Comment: because it's the ranges provided in the example (though perhaps a0 would also be included)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value' : ['a', 'b'],
    'range1' : [0, 4],
    'range2' : [3, 6],
    'color' : ['blue', 'yellow']
})
df['output'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x['value'] + str(i + 1) for i in range(x['range1'], x['range2'])], axis=1)
df = df.explode('output', ignore_index=True)[['output', 'value', 'color']]
print(df)
```

Output

```
  output value   color
0     a1     a    blue
1     a2     a    blue
2     a3     a    blue
3     b5     b  yellow
4     b6     b  yellow
```

Comment: Thank you, this works nicely. Although as Eshirvan mentioned, the counter doesn't include the starting number (at 0). How would you update it for that?

Comment: To have `a` include 0 through 2 (instead of 1 through 3), just change `str(i + 1)` to `str(i)`. To have `a` include 0 through 3, also change `range(x['range1'], x['range2'])` to `range(x['range1'], x['range2'] + 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that it's not clear why range 0 is not counted,

but here is one way:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.range2 - df.range1+1)]
df['output'] = df.value + (df.range1 + df.groupby('value').cumcount()).map(str)
```

output:

```
>>
  value  range1  range2   color output
0     a       0       3    blue     a0
0     a       0       3    blue     a1
0     a       0       3    blue     a2
0     a       0       3    blue     a3
1     b       4       6  yellow     b4
1     b       4       6  yellow     b5
1     b       4       6  yellow     b6
```

Comment: Thank you, this almost did it, but in some of the data starts copying the first range, and then just duplicates that, rather than incrementing.

Comment: @JrTee hmm… what you explained can’t happene with that code , have to see some data for those cases . Anyways seems like you got yours answer already but if you are dealing with large data , apply() func is slow

Comment: Thanks Eshirvana, appreciate the help :)